# No other moderates in this forum? can any person help me?

Tags: discussion

you should help and learn new users. you should not use your power to removed them from contributing!!!!

the detail of my previous question and problem was be in end of the text in box.

**all things that I now, one moderate use his force incorrectly against a new user. 
I think the right with me. because I do not spread any spam or post any unrelated answer.**

I will add more detail of my discussion at here.

1- I am a new user and can not put more that two links in my answer.

2- It seems that your site has a bug, that count the uploaded image's links as a user writing links. If not, the site warning should say you can not put more than two links and Images in one answer! not only warning about links.

3- a moderate delete my correct answer with out asked me.

some answers that he told me was not logical.

4- the answer of moderate is: "it's your problem."
OK, it's my problem that I do not have enough reputation point for post my answer in detail.
So I solved my problem by two way._________
1) upload my complete answer as PDF file and put the link's of it. __________
2) I try to put my answer in 5 answer box. that each of them contain two links or two images.

why he add more problem by deleting answers? by his work I can not put my answer that it was correct. and I can no longer add answer.
also no other person put the correct answer.

This means the moderate not only not-allowed me to posts correct answer, but also he does not put correct answer.

he say you can not add a link of your answer.______
you can not post answer in multiple answer box.______
so how can a new user put his answer with detail (If needed more images and link?)

he can solve my problem in many ways. he can put my entire answer in one answer and can asked me for deleting other parts. or he can get positive point to my answer to I be allowed to put more link in one answer.

5- he should help me. not removed my correct answer.

6- I asked why you add "point -1". he said: [one of the reasons for downvoting an answer is "This answer is not useful" (which you can see if you hover over the downvote link)]

but my answer is correct. and do not need to downvoting. 
he use his power incorrectly.

if even I put a not correct answer he can downvoting my answer. but he use his power to delete it too!

7- for another deleted answer, he said: "We like definitive answers. Not something that might work."

I asked other moderate. do all solutions work for all users? work for all programs?

8- 
all things that I understand, he instead of investigation the warning of sites, he prejudice and deleting my answers.

9- I need a moderate help me by undeleting my answers. If needed I will edit and put one answer.

10- your site has another problem, that a moderate can delete a answer completely with out any voting and responsibility.

**at last, I will be appreciative to any one whose can solve my problem.**

**Excuse me for any unintelligible sentence. because of my English writing does not good.**

.

.

details of my previous question and problem 
    Excuse me for asking my question here. I can not ask my question in meta user because of I do not have 5 point reputation.

```
I wrote a correct answer to this post. 
https://superuser.com/questions/1125300/my-keyboard-num-lock-button-is-missing/1230884#1230884

my answer is completely answer a problem that asked on other forums (below link). and may asked in this forum with similar sentences.
http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/no-num-lock-key-on-my-laptop/2/

I also had this problem with my new laptop keyboard for months. 
and I find a solution for it.
now I'd like to put my answer in this forum, to can help other people.


my answer is true and safe.

I expend more than 5 hours to write the solution in English.

but a moderate whose name is "DavidPostill" deleting my correct answer.

my question is:
why my correct answer was deleted ? 
and why also set "-1 point" to all my answers ?

if I had mistake and you see it; you should tell me this mistake. After you say it to me, I delete my post or answer, as soon as possible.

"**-1 point**" is for unrelated answer. for harmful answer.
there is not for a mistake


also my another answer was deleted (below link). but with a comment that my suggested program be a crapware.
https://superuser.com/questions/378480/windows-move-programs-with-registry-entries-to-a-different-hard-drive/1229595?noredirect=1#comment1801747_1229595

I also need such program for move an installed software to the new PC. 
I installed my suggested program on my PC (win7). and donot see any warning from "Node32 antivirus". 
before that I think can help other by put my finding answer to other people questions.
I also search it in Persian(my own language) forums. other super computer users install that program. and also they put manual for how can used that software. I think that software was not crapware.


but if that moderate ("DavidPostill" that deleted my answer) knowing that this software was a crapware, it's better to tell us by put a reply or answer. he can help other by notice that this program not safe. 

after he deleted my post, why he add "-1 point" to my answer? 

**is here Facebook ?** put like or unlike to others post simply?

did I not correctly understand those questions? 

did I put unrelated answer?

did I put a virus? 

why?


In two above Questions, some other users post obviously incorrect answers. they don't understand the question. why their answers not deleted? not "Point -1". but my correct answer was deleted.


I thought this forum is a good place for put my answers to questions that not answered in the entire web (at least by my strongest search) or at least not answered at this forum.
I thought can help other people too.
but it seems I am in wrong!


**Excuse me for any unintelligible sentence. because my writing English does not good.**
```

Comment: The main problem would probably be your attempt to work around the restrictions that apply to new users. They’re there for a reason. If you cannot answer the question while obeying those restrictions, just don’t answer at all. You can collect some reputation elsewhere and then perhaps answer later.

Comment: I understand what you say. and thanks for your comment.
but I asked why correct answer was deleted.

Comment: if even my answer is unrelated, it be similar to other users answers. it not need to deleted or point -1"

Comment: Note that deleted questions’ and answers’ ratings do not count against your reputation, both positive and negative.

Comment: There is an edit link on the answer you posted, to add more details, but instead you start spamming multiple times in new answer posts. If it was a correct answer, why is it posted in parts?

Comment: @random It’s stated in the deleted answer: New users can post at most two links/images, to prevent spam/ads.

Comment: If you can only post two links then one way around it is to post "dead" links either via a code block or otherwise an obvious link but with a space breaking the "http" section or similar. Then a helpful user with more reputation could repair the links and thereby keep all the information in one place.

Comment: thanks for this "Note that deleted questions’ and answers’ ratings do not count against your reputation, both positive and negative." 

it's very good. and I become calm.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks. I will used this later. ________ 
but for images in the text can not remove this http. it may be not work. _______ my text had only two links. and other links be for images. _____ it seems the bug of this forum. that can not detect upload image's link, from other links.

Comment: @Daniel excuse me can you undelete my answers? 
I can not put answer on the keyboard question. but I'd like to put my answer.
______
or if you can copy pase my answer. 
that I add it in the deleted answers by editing it now.
________
also you said "deleted questions’ and answers’ ratings do not count against your reputation, " but you can see that I can not post again completly!! 
all my post were correctly. the right is with me. but completely delete. by one. :-( :-(  
I donot recome back to yours forum. ____ it is prejudicial and Racism.

Comment: @mostafaa. Your answer being deleted has nothing to due with you as the author but has everything to do with the quality of the answer.  How can somebody be racist towards somebody when they know absolutely nothing about you.  Edit your answer, improve the quality of the answer, and if 5 people agree it will be undeleted.  If you cannot answer the question without active links to a website, find another question to answer, until you have more reputation in order to provide more active links.

Comment: Word of warning.  If your answer is to recommend software that installs "crapware" very few people with enough reputation to see your deleted answer will vote to restore it.  In addition every answer you did submit had numerous grammatical mistakes, your answers, were in an unreadable state.  If you were answered banned, then nothing can be done, except for you to improve the quality of an answer to that question and every other answer you submitted to other question that have also been deleted because users don't get answer banned after 4 answers

Answer (score 8):

> I wrote a correct answer to this post. [My keyboard Num Lock button is missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1125300/my-keyboard-num-lock-button-is-missing)

You wrote 3 different answers, each adding some extra information to your previous answer.

That is not how Stack Exchange works. Answers should be self contained (and complete).

Please read and take note of [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Note that it does not mention writing multiple answers, each of which builds on the answer you have already written.

Your first answer said:

> so I upload my answer as pdf file at here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7EY10I144RfQzM1T1JGUG1oTzA

That is a link-only answer (not a correct answer). Link only answers are not allowed as:

> Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

You also said:

> I am a new user, cannot add more than two links in my answer

You only need 10 reputation points to overcome this limit:

> What are the new user restrictions?
>
> New users cannot:
>
> - post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile
> - contribute answers to protected questions
> - ask or answer questions too rapidly

If you write good answers it is easy to obtain 10 reputation points (only 1 upvote is required).

> and also write my answer in the 5 next comments. search KKKK for find all my answers.

That is not the way you should write answers on the Stack Exchange network.

> also my another answer was deleted (below link). but with a comment that my suggested program be a crapware. [Windows: Move programs (with registry entries) to a different hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/378480/windows-move-programs-with-registry-entries-to-a-different-hard-drive).

From the [link that you quoted in that deleted answer](https://www.maketecheasier.com/transfer-programs-from-one-pc-to-another/):

> PickMeApp is still in beta so the publisher does not give any direct
> download link of the app. You will need to register with the service
> and then download and install the app on your computer. Go to
> PickMeApp download page and register with your email address and
> personal information. Once you confirm the registration through email,
> you will be able to download the app using the same URL.
>
> A word of caution about the installation process, you should be
> careful while installing PickMeApp as it will install extra software
> (crapware) which seems like agreeing to the terms and conditions of
> the software usage.

This is not the kind of software that we like our user to recommend.

> -1 point" is for unrelated answer. for harmful answer. there is not for a mistake

Voting is anonymous and no reason has to be given for a downvote.

Having said that, one of the reasons for downvoting an answer is "This answer is not useful" (which you can see if you hover over the downvote link).

It would appear that someone though your multiple (incomplete) answers to the same question were not useful.

> In two above Questions, some other users post obviously incorrect answers. they don't understand the question.

The other answers were not obviously incorrect. If you think they are then you should downvote and/or add a comment when you have sufficient reputation.

> I thought this forum is a good place for put my answers to questions that not answered in the entire web (at least by my strongest search)

The Stack Exchange sites are **not** forums. Please take some time and read the [help centre articles](https://superuser.com/help) so you can see how things work here.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it's to long for me, I will answer it in about 1  hours.

first you say "You wrote 3 different answers ... " 
I wrote one answer. but at last I can not send it. because of more than 2 images and links in the answer. 

I try to upload my answer and write it in 4-5 part. to it become searchable for googles.

and that is not the my last text. I was going to better it. may be by delete some of them.
I do not think anyone read my answers now (because the post was be for 9 moth ago). and I have time to put my part of text and edit them.

Comment: also I look for set comment on my first answer instead of more answers. but can not see this option.

Comment: @mostafaa You wrote three different answers (labelled part 0, part 1 and part 2)

Comment: @mostafaa You can edit your answers.

Comment: another thing you said "Link only answers are not allowed as:
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change." 
--------------
I also try to write my answer on the forum too. but can not put it in one answer. because the my upload file may be moved or deleted.

Comment: also I will be going to move my answer to where that the question is better matched to entire my answer. and put an smaller answer to that question. 
I do not think any one reaction very fast to my answer. 
that is my mistake. I should write my text completely. and check it's problems and then put it. 
but I'd like to start and change improve my answer.

Comment: "@mostafaa You wrote three different answers (labelled part 0, part 1 and part 2) " 
there are not three different answer.
my english not good. I tray to say I puts the answer in the 5 "answer box" . or five part.

Comment: I read your answer completely. my English not good and can not answer.

but I try to answer some of them.

Comment: That is your problem. We don't allow multi-part answers.

Comment: "PickMeApp is still in beta so the publisher does not give any direct download link of the app. You will need to register ...."

yes it need registration. 
but I download it from other sites. that are in Persian and can not put in the "superuser" forum.
some other people installed it. and don't say any harmful action from this. I try it too. but it does not help me in move an old software. 
but I think it may be useful for some other.

Comment: @mostafaa We like definitive answers. Not something that **might** work.

Comment: "That is your problem. We don't allow multi-part answers." 
.Ok. but you can say this to me. 
also you delete all my answers. not more than one!. you can asked me for put only one answer. 
because the site was allowed me to put more than one answer.
and it seems you donot allowing me. 
also I asked for other helps to re-write my answer in fluent English. and can put all parts in one answer. and i will delete my parts answer

Comment: "We like definitive answers. Not something that might work**. it's write. but some answers not definitive . and if an answer was definitive it check marked to answer. and get more points. it's an answer like other answers. and may be not need deleting. but I accept you for deleting this. because you say it crapware. and at least it helpful for me. to uninstall this software

Comment: at last I would like to ask if it possible un-delete my answers (in the keyboard question). I will put one answer. and delete others. my answer is correct. I donot put any other answer. because the site warning me about it may be blocking me from answer in future

Comment: also thank you for the time that you spend for me. to answer to my question.

Comment: The only way your answer will be restored is if your answer (singular) is modified and it by itself answers the question.  If 5 people agree to undelete the answer it can be restored without a moderator.  The only way you will avoid an answer ban is if you improve your answer.  Once an answer ban happens it is impossible for anyone to override the ban.